# ERROr ITMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value.The value for the key 'CFBundleExecutable' in bundle .app/PlugIns/ServiceExtension.appex is invalid

Tags: ios, app-store

HII have added Service extension for push notifications  and when I am trying to upload app to the AppStore but I am getting errors.PLEASE FIND THE error image attached below.[image]

this is my ServiceExtension  is attached below [image]

[image]

I am trying to upload to Appstore thanks for quick responce

Comment: I fixed it by creating multiple extensions because I am working with multiple targets in our project , it solved my issue.